# How do I debug a request in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My computer restarted and my app no longer works today. It was working yesterday. Nothing changed except Maven downloading new libraries (mostly Amazon). Now I can't even access the `/admin/login` page. How do I debug the request?

```
2019-09-13 17:26:16.924  INFO 2056 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/admin/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.s.s.controller.Controller.login()
2019-09-13 17:26:21.465 ERROR 2056 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.c.Controller     : invalidRequest(): invalid request: /admin/login
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String login() {
    return "login";
}
@RequestMapping("/error")
public void invalidRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    Logger.error(TAG, "invalidRequest()", "invalid request: " + request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI));
    try {
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        response.getWriter().write("This is not a valid request");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.error(TAG, "invalidRequest: ", "Exception in invalidRequest() method "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return "/error";
}
```

I set this line in `application.properties` but it didn't print anything extra.

```
logging.level.com.s.s.controller.Controller=DEBUG
```

I ran `mvn clean` and restarted server, but it didn't help.

I set this line in `application.properties` but it didn't print anything useful.

```
debug=true
```

Log:

```
2019-09-13 17:40:25.459 DEBUG 2056 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4d3e8c3a
2019-09-13 17:40:25.460 DEBUG 2056 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4d3e8c3a

2019-09-13 17:40:25.463 ERROR 2056 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.c.Controller     : invalidRequest(): invalid request: /admin/login
2019-09-13 17:40:25.477 DEBUG 2056 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4d3e8c3a
2019-09-13 17:40:25.484 DEBUG 2056 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4d3e8c3a
```

---

```
$ git status
        modified:   src/main/resources/application.properties 
        modified:   src/main/resources/static/js/home.js
```

---

I compared libraries to what was last deployed and the only changes were

```
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.631.jar
aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.631.jar
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.631.jar
aws-java-sdk-ses-1.11.631.jar
jmespath-java-1.11.631.jar
```

---

I commented `public String getErrorPath()` and `public void invalidRequest()` and now it gives me

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Sep 13 18:59:03 UTC 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
No message available
```

But with `curl` it gives

```
$ curl localhost:8080/admin/login
{"timestamp":1568401131164,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"No message available","path":"/admin/login"}
```

---

I found the following searching for `spring-sleuth` in Makgigrahul's answer and added it to `application.properties` producing this log.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=DEBUG
```

Log:

```
2019-09-13 16:10:11.329 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-13 16:10:11.330  INFO 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-13 16:10:11.331  INFO 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2019-09-13 16:10:11.332 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@6481dcd8]
2019-09-13 16:10:11.332 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using LocaleResolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@50cc90f2]
2019-09-13 16:10:11.339 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@135fd762]
2019-09-13 16:10:11.345 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@61cc4a6b]
2019-09-13 16:10:11.352 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@766c1f26]
2019-09-13 16:10:11.353 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServlet]
2019-09-13 16:10:11.355  INFO 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 23 ms
2019-09-13 16:10:11.356 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' configured successfully
2019-09-13 16:10:11.376 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2019-09-13 16:10:11.383 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2019-09-13 16:10:11.408 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@53191939] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-13 16:10:11.415 DEBUG 15356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

---

Comment: Can you debug on your IDE?

Comment: Setting the log level for `org.springframework.http` and `org.springframework.web` to `DEBUG` is a good starting point.

Comment: @Mike I set them and this is the result: https://www.pastiebin.com/5d7bfaf6f1eb1

Comment: @Chloe hmm, not much there...can you also set `DEBUG` level for `org.springframework.security` and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set a breakpoint in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#doFilter. Thats pretty at the beginning of the request processing. Or you can have a look in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet#doDispatch

Comment: How do I debug within Eclipse? I tried to add a server (Apache) but it asks for Tomcat installation directory. Spring Boot uses an embedded Tomcat server. I normally run the app with `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: You can start the class with the main method in debug mode. Its the one annotated with @SpringBootApplication. And ApplicationFilterChain should be in your maven dependencies. So you can just open these classen in Eclipse to set a breakpoint. You don't have to add a server. Spring boot has an embedded tomcat server included

Answer (score 1):

I was able to debug using Andreas' answer and saw the values for `request.request.filterChain.filters[]` and saw my filter `remoteAddressFilter()` and saw `remoteAddress = 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`. I have an IP filter ([`RemoteAddrFilter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/RemoteAddrFilter.html)) and one of the allowed values is `127.0.0.1`. I was accessing the server with `http://localhost:8080/admin/home`, which apparently uses the IP6 address. Probably a Windows update which restarted the computer changed the networking behavior. When I use `http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/home` it works. I would like to add logging to the filter to notify when blocked, but there is no apparent way. Amazing Spring doesn't log the filters in debug mode.